# htaccess stop processing rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to be able to run the rules at CakePHP block if my IP matches the Maintenance Mode conditions otherwise ignore them, possible? Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Maintenance Mode
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/offline\.php$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(00\.00\.00\.00)
RewriteRule .* /offline\.php [L]

# CakePHP
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Maintenance Mode
RewriteRule ^offline\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/offline\.php$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=192.168.0.2
RewriteRule .* /offline.php [L]

# CakePHP
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/webroot/
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

1. Use your own IP address
2. I have added condition to the very last rule to prevent rewrite loop

Comment: If I access the website with an invalid IP the server looks for offline.php in app/webroot resulting in a 404. mmmm.

Comment: @woodscreative I have updated my answer -- the `RewriteRule ^offline\.php$ - [L]` line should do the job ensuring that once rewritten offline URL will not get passed to CakePHP.

Comment: @woodscreative Check Apache error log for exact error description -- I have just re-tested .. and it works fine for me (I do not have CakePHP, but I have created similar rewrite rule to catch all URLs). Try copy-paste those rules again (maybe is was not saved/uploaded properly).